# How to serve files generated by sbt-js using spray-can

Tags: scala, classloader, spray

This is probably a very basic thing, but I just can't get it to work. To the [spray-template](https://github.com/spray/spray-template/) project I have added the [sbt-js](https://github.com/untyped/sbt-plugins/tree/develop/sbt-js) plugin.

When I run the `js` command it finds and processes my js files in `src/main/[resources]/web/js/` and places them in `target/scala-2.11/resource_managed/[main]/resources/web/js/`

(The [ ] marks directories that shows up as resource directories in intellij).

I try to serve up the js files something like this, but it only works for the unprocessed file:

```
trait JsContent extends HttpService {
  val jsRoute = path("js1") {
    getFromResource("web/js/test.js") // The unprocessed js file loads fine.
  } ~ path("js2") {
    getFromResource("resources/web/js/test.js") // How do I locate the generated file?
  }
}
```

The directory containing the processed files is listed when doing `show resourceDirectories` in sbt console, but they are not included in the jar produced when running package.

So how to point out to sbt that I want to use the managed js resources?

Comment: You could try running `package` and then just look in the generated jar where the resources end up.

Comment: The generated files are not included in the resulting jar file, only the source ones. The documentation for sbt-js states that If you're using xsbt-web-plugin (which I'm not), you should add `(webappResources in Compile) <+= (resourceManaged in Compile)`, so I guess I'm looking for something similar.